# VisualStates and DataTriggerBehaviors

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have defined a custom VisualState for an AppBarButton in a Style.

I'm trying to use GoToStateAction to change the state with a DataTriggerBehavior, but it doesn't work and I have no idea how to debug it :(

I'm guessing that it is an issue with Interaction in a style, as I also tried changing the DataTriggerBehavior to an EventTriggerBehavior and that didn't fire either.

The Style:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:eim="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
xmlns:vm="using:Test.ViewModel">

<Style x:Key="AppBarBtnStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                <Border x:Name="bord" CornerRadius="12" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="4">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding FlashControl}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="{TemplateBinding Name}" >
                                <core:GoToStateAction StateName="Flash"/>
                            </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Flash">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Root.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" EnableDependentAnimation="True" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False">
                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Blue" KeyTime="0:0:0.75"/>
                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:1"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The Binding Property:

```
    Private mFlashControl As String
    Public Property FlashControl() As String
        ' The Name of the Control to Flash 
        Get
            Return mFlashControl
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetProperty(mFlashControl, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

The Button:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="myButton" Style="{StaticResource AppBarBtnStyle}" Icon="Clock"/>
```

So if I set the FlashControl Property to "myButton", all the Buttons with that Style will run the DataTriggerBehavior to check if their Name Property matches that of FlashControl.

If a match is found then the VisualState of the Button will be changed and run the flash Storyboard.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue that you mentioned,and I have reported this bug to related team. Currently, if you want to realize this behavior, you could control the animation in the code behind.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Did you have any luck discovering where the problem originates ? ie. is it the trigger or the gotostate ?

Comment: I've discovered that VisualStateManager only works with Controls and not FrameworkElements.  If I put the VSM block in the Border then I can change the state with an event trigger.  Still no luck with the Datatrigger though.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Do you have any update on this?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT If it's any help, I have  a sample project at.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AraXP7LtRcVmneRxjkjTORd5HeQH_A